# Are timeline semaphore counters atomic? Do they need to be?

Tags: vulkan

If I have two submissions A and B. 'A' signals 6 on the timeline semaphore counter, and 'B' signals 10 on the timeline semaphore counter.

Another submission C, waits on timeline semaphore counter 8.

Is the counter atomic so that if B finishes before A, B sets the counter to 10, then A finishes and tries to write 6, sees that it's lower than the counter value already and then doesn't write it? Therefore C can proceed correctly (waiting on the highest signal value) regardless of which order A and B are completed in? Does the capability afforded by this counter mean the counter must be atomic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value stored in a timeline sem is required to be monotonically increasing. The application is responsible for ensuring that signalling occurs in the right order to ensure that behavior holds true.

> Is the counter atomic so that if B finishes before A, B sets the counter to 10, then A finishes and tries to write 6 ...

This is out-of-spec. In this scenario the application must insert pipeline barriers/fences/dependencies to ensure that A signals before B does.